# JSF ViewScoped OutOfMemoryException

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

I have a JSF application with a `@ViewScoped` bean. It is `viewScoped` because I do some ajax requests.

I load a big amount of data into the view and display it to the user.

Today I performed a load test and I ran into an `OutOfMemoryException`. As it turns out, when I open the page, `@PostConstruct` is called

`bean created. ID = @54a35e23`

Now I navigate to another page and return again (`@PreDestroy` was not called) Then I get

`bean created. ID = @fee0948`

I do this all over again in the load test. And a few hours later I have the `OutOfMemoryException`

Can I somehow force JSF to destroy my `ViewScoped` bean when I navigat to another page?

Comment: Do you use CDI or are you open to? OmniFaces `@ViewScoped` explicitly destroys beans and associated JSF view state during onload. But it requires CDI. See also http://showcase.omnifaces.org/cdi/ViewScoped

Comment: I use java ee 6 and no CDI. Additionally I am very close to go live so I don't want to change lot. Is there no other way?

Comment: JSF (Mojarra) keeps a max of 25 view scoped beans in session. Alter memory space on that. Or, introduce 2nd level JPA cache (if you're using JPA).

Comment: can I somehow reduce 25 to 3 ?

Comment: Not without hacking the impl. There's no public setting for that.

Comment: I disabled the JPA L2 cache because of stale data in my cluster

Comment: @BalusC when you say it stores 25 view scoped beans. That means when I refreh the page for the 26th time, the 1st view scoped beans's PreDestroy method should be called, correct?

Comment: It will evict physical bean from LRU map in session, no worries, but whether its `@PreDestroy` method is called depends on JSF version. This is only fixed since 2.2. See also OmniFaces `@ViewScoped` javadoc/showcase for explanation/links on this problem.

Comment: okay thanks. I wonder, would it be a good idea to change from viewScoped to SessionScoped? Therefore it would not create so many instances

Comment: Depends on scope of the data. See also http://stackoverflow.com/q/7031885

Answer (score 0):

If you ViewScoped bean is huge, you have a problem with your implementation. Could you add your source to review it. If you're handling a huge data amount, you probably need to use something in memory grid like Infinispan or Hazelcast

Comment: but when I want to use some ajax request within my page I have to use ViewScope or SessionScope, right?

Comment: Yes, but I'm talking about the data that you're showing on your page, which components are you showing?